# Barman Postgres 14 recovery

Tags: postgresql, docker, barman

I updated my postgres from 10 to 14 few weeks ago. The recovery used to work before (restoring the backup on a different postgres server):

1. Put the barman backup into the folder

```
ssh -i ./do.pem root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "docker exec barman_1 barman recover --target-time=$(date --iso-8601=seconds) db latest /var/lib/barman/recovered"
```

2. Copying to the second server

```
rsync -e "ssh -i ./do.pem" -r root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/mnt/volume_fra1_01/barman/recovered .
```

3. Overriding the settings

```
rm -r postgres
mkdir -p postgres/14/data
mv recovered/* postgres/14/data
rm postgres/14/data/postgresql.auto.conf
echo "max_connections = '2000'" > postgres/14/data/postgresql.auto.conf
```

4. Docker-compose up

```
docker-compose up db
```

5. So it used to work (postgres 10 started to copy WAL from barman files) and I had to turn off the recovery mode executing sql command on the db. However with Postgres 14 it doesn't work. Db logs

```
db_1  |
db_1  | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
db_1  |
db_1  | 2022-01-08 10:01:08.610 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.1 (Debian 14.1-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
db_1  | 2022-01-08 10:01:08.610 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1  | 2022-01-08 10:01:08.610 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db_1  | 2022-01-08 10:01:08.613 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1  | 2022-01-08 10:01:08.620 UTC [27] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2022-01-07 16:44:21 UTC
db_1  | 2022-01-08 10:01:08.785 UTC [27] FATAL:  must specify restore_command when standby mode is not enabled
db_1  | 2022-01-08 10:01:08.787 UTC [1] LOG:  startup process (PID 27) exited with exit code 1
db_1  | 2022-01-08 10:01:08.787 UTC [1] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
db_1  | 2022-01-08 10:01:08.806 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

There is a recovery.signal file in the postgres/14/data folder.

```
root@dev:~/targ-app/postgres/14/data# ls -a
.           backup_label     base          pg_dynshmem    pg_logical    pg_replslot   pg_stat      pg_tblspc    pg_xact                      postgresql.conf         recovery.signal
..          backup_manifest  global        pg_hba.conf    pg_multixact  pg_serial     pg_stat_tmp  pg_twophase  postgresql.auto.conf         postgresql.conf.origin
PG_VERSION  barman_wal       pg_commit_ts  pg_ident.conf  pg_notify     pg_snapshots  pg_subtrans  pg_wal       postgresql.auto.conf.origin  postmaster.opts
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer

```
restore_command = 'cp barman_wal/%f %p'
recovery_end_command = 'rm -fr barman_wal'
recovery_target_time = '2022-01-08T17:07:14+00:00'
```

Comment: Please add details about what the effect of this code is, and how it answers the question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure barman wrote the required configuration in postgresql.auto.conf. But you deleted it. Before postgresql 12, the pitr configuration was written to a different file `recovery.conf`.